# Maximize the sum of interval lengths in intersection of interval sets

Tags: algorithm, set

We have `n` sets of intervals, where each set `S_i` is consists of non-overlapping intervals `[A_i_1, B_i_1]`, `[A_i_2, B_i_2]`, ...

Given a positive integer `k` (where `k <= n`), we want to find `k` sets out of the `n` sets that maximize the sum of the length of the intervals formed by taking intersections of those `k` sets. Here, taking intersections of the `k` sets means we form a set of intervals `[C_1, D_1]`, `[C_2, D_2]`, ..., where a `[C_j, D_j]` is contained in each of the `k` interval sets, meaning that for each interval set `i`, `[C_j, D_j]` is contained in some `[A_i_l, B_i_l]`.

For example, we have 3 sets of intervals

```
Set 1: [1, 2] [3, 5]
Set 2: [1, 2] [3, 6]
Set 3: [1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]
```

and we want to find 2 sets that maximize their intersections, so here the answer would be `Set 1`, `Set 2` where the intersection is `[1, 2], [3, 5]`, and another answer is `Set 2`, `Set 3` where the intersection is `[1, 2]`, `[3, 4]`, `[5, 6]`.

This problem came from a practical situation where I want to find a maximum set of dates from several sets of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.11.2135&rep=rep1&type=pdf) shows that this is NP-hard.